# Unable to connect with AWS Aurora PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework and AWS Aurora PostgreSQL with node-express.
When i am trying connect with PostgreSQL locally it is working fine, but when i am  deploying the app on aws (lambda function), it's not working.

Log error is like :

```
 ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5000
}
```

here is my code :

```
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg");
 const client = new Client({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "my_cluster.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  database: "postgres",
  password: "passwor",
  port: 5000,
});

     client.connect().then(
      (data) => {
        console.log("Successfully connected to Postgres");
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("Error While Connecting to Postgres", err);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Why would there be `127.0.0.1` in error message if you are using `my_cluster.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` as host?

Comment: no idea...but it works on local